# Retrieve SOAP Request Valid from XSD

Tags: soap, request, xsd, soapui

I have this kind of "guidelines" to call a SOAP service:

[image]

URL: http://80.211.113.172:8080/soap

**No WSDL at all!**

The XSD for request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="/soap_serv" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAPENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAPENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:TRACKING>
    <ldv xsi:type="xsd:string">2020.00.0070423</ldv>
    <codcli xsi:nil="true"/>
    <rifcli xsi:nil="true"/>
    <anno_bl xsi:nil="true"/>
  </ns1:TRACKING>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Does anyone know how to create a request object to send with SoapUI?

Comment: That's not an XSD, it's an example SOAP request. You cannot derive a WSDL from a single SOAP request. You should ask the team that owns the service to provide a WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

The XML you are showing isn't an XML Schema (or XSD file). As pointed out in the comment by @kimbert, that is actually an SOAP XML message. The payload inside it is what an XML instance of an XSD schema would be.

You have two options:

- ask for a WSDL for the web service so that you can generate some client code to help you with the calls.
- if a WSDL is not available, ask for better documentation for how to call the service. Not sure where you got that example but is the operation name `TRACKING`? Is the `ns1` prefix pointing to the correct namespace? Should the elements inside the `TRACKING` element also be in this namespace? Note also that you are using `codcli` and `rifcli` in your call, when that guideline shows `cod_cli` and `rif_cli`. You most likely also need to send values for your elements, not have them null like that.

Not having a WSDL or valid up to date documentation for how the exchanged messages should look like will make things very difficult for you in interacting with the web service.